# Constraint to require a certain number of matches

Tags: optaplanner, constraint-programming

I am trying to write a hard constraint that requires that a certain value has been chosen a certain number of times. I have a constraint written below, which (I think) filters to a set of results that match this criteria, and I want it to penalize if there are no such results. I cannot figure out how to work `.ifNotExists()` into this. I think I am missing some understanding.

```kotlin
      fun cpMustUseN(constraintFactory: ConstraintFactory): Constraint {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(MealMenu::class.java)
            .join(CpMustUse::class.java, equal({ mm -> mm.slottedCp!!.id }, CpMustUse::cpId))
            .groupBy({ _, cpMustUse -> cpMustUse.numRequired }, countBi())
            .filter { numRequired, count -> count >= numRequired }
            .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
            .asConstraint("cpMustUseN")
      }
```

`MealMenu` is an entity:

```kotlin
@PlanningEntity
class MealMenu {
    @PlanningId
    var id = 0

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = ["cpRange"])
    var slottedCp: Cp? = null
}
```

`CpMustUse` is a `@ProblemFactCollectionProperty` on my solution class, and the class looks like this:

```kotlin
class CpMustUse {
    var cpId = 1
    var numRequired = 4
}
```

I want to, in this case, constrain the result such that `cpId` 1 is chosen at least 4 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two conceptual issues here:

1. `groupBy()` will only match if the join returns a non-zero number of matches. Therefore you will never get a `countBi()` of zero - in that case, `groupBy()` will simply never match. Therefore you can not use grouping to check that something does not exist.
2. `ifNotExists()` always applies to a fact from the working memory. You can not use it to check if a result of a previous calculation exists.

Combined together, this makes your approach infeasible. This particular requirement will be a bit trickier to implement.

Start by inverting the logic of the constraint you pasted. Penalize every time `count < numRequired`; this handles all cases where `count >= 1`.
Then introduce a second constraint that will handle specifically the case where the count would be zero - in this case, you should be able to use `forEach(MealMenu::class.java).ifNotExists(CpMustUse::class, ...)`.